# Please verify my argument for $f_n(x)=x^n$ not uniformly convergent on $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-convergence, cauchy-sequences, sequence-of-function

> $f_n(x)=x^n$ not uniformly convergent on $(0,1)$

I know there are multiple posts on this same question but please verify if my argument is correct or not::

I am convinced that $$f_n \text{ is not uniformly cauchy on D if}$$

$$\exists \epsilon_0>0 \ni\;\forall n \in N \ \; \exists x_0 \in D \; \exists m_0, n_0 \geq n \ni \;$$ (Here, my $x_0, \; n_0,\; m_0$ will depend on $n$)

$$|f_{n_0}(x_0) - f_{m_0}(x_0)|\geq \epsilon_0  -->>(1)$$

Is above intepretation of not unifrom cauchy correct?

so,

$$\exists \epsilon_0=\frac18 >0 \ni\;\forall n \in N  \; \exists \frac1{2^{\frac1n}} \in [0,1] \; \exists n, 2n \geq n \ni \;$$

$$|\big(\frac1{2^{\frac1n}}\big)^n - \big(\frac1{2^{\frac1n}}\big)^{2n}| = |\frac12 - \frac14| = \frac14\geq\epsilon_0$$

So $x^n$ is not uniformly cauchy and hence not uniformly convergent.

Is this correct?

More specifically, is $(1)$ correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Alternatively, the convergence is not uniform since as $n \to \infty$, $\sup_{x \in (0,1)}|f_n(x)-0| \geqslant f_n(2^{-1/n}) = \frac{1}{2} \not\to 0$